# What exactly is the stuff in the middle of the Stargate?

Tags: stargate

The Stargate in Stargate, Stargate: SG-1, and it's derivatives, creates a wormhole between two Stargates, which most of the time has an unstable vortex ***kawoosh*** that tends to destroy anything that's sufficiently away from it's surface, before falling back in and leaving a mostly flat water or pool like surface. **But what is the surface made of?** It tends to ripple like water, but it's obviously not water. And in the season 2 episode "A Matter of Time", a large gravitational force of a black hole on the other side was enough to make it spin down/inwards like an eddy or [whirlpool/maelstrom/vortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlpool).

[image]

In-Universe answer please.

Comment: Just for clarification… you mean in-universe, or how they made the FX?

Comment: In-universe @Tetsujin. Though it be nice to know what they used in sfx.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking at is the [event horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon) of a wormhole linking two points in space. It follows that the "puddle" isn't actually *made* of anything, it's merely a gravitational effect, causing the light in the gate room to be reflected back on itself.

> *"Hello, I'm Doctor Daniel Jackson and behind me is a Stargate. Found in
>   Giza, Egypt, in 1928, we now know it was originally built millennia
>   ago by an alien race who we call the Ancients. Over the next few
>   hours, we'll be touching on some of the things you need to know about
>   the Stargate and how it works. There are 39 symbols representing star
>   constellations as seen from Earth, capable of transporting
>   people—objects—hundreds of thousands of light years via an
>   interstellar wormhole. Within the Milky Way galaxy, a seven-symbol
>   address is used. The first six symbols lock down a point in space,
>   while the seventh symbol represents the point of origin. **When a
>   connection is made between two Stargates, an unstable energy vortex
>   emerges from the 'gate and settles into the event horizon, or
>   "puddle," as we like to call it.***"

Comment: Where did this stuff come from?  DVD extras?

Comment: The "Stargate 101" videos are from Stargate Universe, Air Part 1/2

Answer (score -2):

There has never been any in-universe explanation of any wormhole-type device.  This includes similar wormhole-type devices found in Star Trek, Contact and several other Sci-Fi movies.  My best guess is that if you had actors standing in front of a ring, it wouldn't really have the same impact as having them stand in front of a visual barrier.  By making that barrier liquid-esque (that can't be a real word??), it still shows that there is some unknown on the other side but makes it realistic that someone/something can pass through it.

Out of universe, it may just be a visual manifestation of a magnetic field.

http://www.livescience.com/51925-magnetic-wormhole-created.html

Comment: OP is specific about in-universe answer only.

Comment: OK, figured I'd add an out-of-universe answer as well.  The first line of my answer is still 100% correct.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Do you have evidence for that?  I remember several instances of in-universe explanations for the Star Gate devices.